# Segmentation fault 11 in C on mac

Tags: c

I am unable to read the data from the file created. This is a very simple code and I simply cannot understand why it is not working. I have just shifted to mac and installed the developer command line tools.

My code is :

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int lines = 0;
    char *data;
    data = (char *)malloc(1000);
    data = NULL;

    fp = fopen("1.txt", "r");
    while (fgets(data, 1000, fp) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", data);
        lines++;
    }
    printf("Lines = %d\n", lines);
    free(data);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: Is your data getting lost?

Comment: Hint: what's that `data = NULL;` for?

Comment: Hint2: Read [the man-page for `fgets`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) too. Also, [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845). Let's omit the talk about `fopen` and `malloc` not always succeeding.

Comment: It is not working because you did not debug it, as @OliverCharlesworth says.   If you are not willing/able to debug code, you should not write it because you don't have the required skills.

Answer (score 1):

You allocate space for `data` and then promptly leak it.

```
char *data;
data = (char *)malloc(1000);
data = NULL;
```

You then use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) with a `NULL` pointer, which causes undefined behavior.

```
fgets(data, 1000, fp)
```

Perhaps you should remove this line of code?

```
data = NULL;
```